# Change targeted device family on existing iPhone/iPad app

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4

I uploaded a new app, version 1.0, where the target device family was: iPhone/iPad.

I'm now trying to add a new version, **without iPad support**. The new version should only support iPhone.

The error message I receive is the following:

> "This bundle does not support one or
>   more of the devices that were
>   supported in the previous bundle for
>   this app. Bundles must continue to
>   support any devices previously
>   supported."

Where do I go from here?

Comment: Did you read the error you were getting? It accurately describes the issue at hand.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't go back to non-universal app from universal app. You'll have to create a new app (new bundle ID) with iPhone only if you wish to proceed.

Comment: Okay. And I can't have the same name on the app which is a huge problem?

Comment: And what is the reason for this?

Comment: I hit the same problem. Can't drop device family to Iphone only.
This is the answer from Apple:https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1623/_index.html
They tell you to remove the app and create a new one with different bundle.id but cannot use the same name... And know i'm stucked and don't know what to do...