# phonegap ios app can not set to iphone only

Tags: ios, cordova

I am maintaining an old project which uses phonegap to build ios app.

I want to set my project to iOS only, so I set the **Targeted Device Family** to **iPhone** and I also set the **Build Active Architecture Only** to Yes, but it still not work probably on my iPad. On my iPhone everything is fine, but on my iPad I can see only a part of the contents.

How to fix it?

Comment: So before this, the app was for what? Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410636/change-targeted-device-family-on-existing-iphone-ipad-app)?

Comment: I am not sure if it's an iPhone only app before, but I haven't receive the same error message, actually, there isn't any error message generated. The app can run on iPad, though the view is abnormal.

Answer (score 0):

It would be wise to make sure what kind of bundle it was before. If it was built to be a "universal app" then it will stay universal. If it was built to be iPhone only then it will be iPhone only. Apps are submitted as bundles, they cannot be separated, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18392417/xcode-release-app-update-for-iphone-only?lq=1) and sanfor's comment.